# I have list if Guids and i want to check if any of that guid is present in dictionary as a key

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

i have

```
List<Guid> id
```

My dictionary:

```
manager.DriveTimes.Containskey(id)
```

How can i check if any of the id is present as a key in dictionary.
I want to check in one go without using for loop against List id.

Any suggesttion

Answer (score 2):

```
idList.Any(id => manager.DriveTimes.ContainsKey(id));
```

Comment: +1 definitely a better option to use Dictionary's `ContainsKey`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Intersect** extension from **System.Linq**.

```
bool anyGuids = manager.DriveTimes.Keys.Intersect(id).Any()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completedness, here are some performance comparisons

```
        List<Guid> listA = new List<Guid>();
        for (int count = 0; count < 10000; count++)
        {
            listA.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        }

        List<Guid> listB = new List<Guid>();
        for (int count = 0; count < 10000; count++)
        {
            listB.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        }

        // Match by Any without matches.
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        bool matchFound = listA.Any(item => listB.Contains(item));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("List Match {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Guid, string> dictA = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Guid, string>();
        for (int count = 0; count < 10000; count++)
        {
            dictA.Add(Guid.NewGuid(),"");
        }

        // Match by Key without matches.
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        matchFound = listB.Any(item => dictA.ContainsKey(item));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Key Match {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

These give results

```
        List Match 1095ms
        Key Match 1ms
```